# Running Kafka consumers on Docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm fairly new to Kafka and I'm using the Confluent Kafka Python API. 
I plan to create consumers that run in docker containers. 
I'm wondering as to what the best practice is for running Kafka consumers on Docker. Specifically, should I run a single consumer within a single container ? Given the issues with multi-threading in Python,  I'm wondering if this may be the safest approach. Any suggestions/insights are welcome.

Comment: You really only have two options - threads or more containers. Have you tried either? What issues are you having?

Comment: So is using 1 container per consumer a viable strategy ? I'd like to avoid threads in Python because of GIL issues.

Comment: I don't see why not